# What Does Ruby's Array#shift do?

Tags: ruby

I am having a hard time understanding what the shift and unshift methods of the Array class do in Ruby. Can somebody help me understand what they do?

Comment: Once you learn that `shift/unshift` are like `push/pop` on the other end of the array, you can mentally drop the 'f' from the name of the methods to remember which one 'dumps' elements and which one 'inserts' them. :)

Comment: One of the best comments ever! Thanks you so much :)

Comment: @Phrogz Actually, vertebrate digestive systems are better modeled as queues than as stacks.

Comment: @Jian :) Right: `push` it into the top, and `shift` it out the other end.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Looking at the [Ruby Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002170)

Array.shift removes the first element from the array and returns it

```
a = [1,2,3] 
puts a.shift
 => 1 
puts a
 => [2, 3]
```

Unshift prepends the provided value to the front of the array, moving all other elements up one

```
a=%w[b c d]
 => ["b", "c", "d"] 
a.unshift("a")
 => ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Comment: You can basically think of shift and unshift as being operations on a FIFO queue

Comment: @JacoPretorius Huh? `shift` and `unshift` act like a FILO stack, `push` and `shift` would act like a FIFO queue, unless I am confused about something.

Comment: @GregSchmit Ah, you're right.  Or actually, a LIFO queue, right?

Comment: @JacoPretorius Well I think LIFO == FILO (first in last out implies that the last one in must come out first if the pattern holds).

Comment: @JacoPretorius Both LIFO and FILO mean "behave like a stack".

Answer (score 60):

[`shift`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002170) and [`unshift`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002171) acts in similar way as [`pop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002169) and [`push`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002168): they are meant to use arrays as stacks to which you can append and remove elements (usually one per time). The difference is just that `shift` and `unshift` add/remove elements at the beginning of an `Array`, actually *shift*ing all other elements, while `pop` and `push` add/remove elements at the end of the `Array`, so preserving other elements' indices.

Examples:

```
                      # Spacing for clarity:
a = [2, 4, 8]    # a =>       [2, 4, 8]
a.push(16, 32)   # a =>       [2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
a.unshift(0, 1)  # a => [0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
a.shift          # a =>    [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
a.pop            # a =>    [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
```

Comment: If you were to edit your answer to summarize the the mipadi thread, I would be glad to upvote.

Comment: Cool. Also, I'm not very knowledgeable about Ruby, but if it runs on the JVM then I would expect that push/pop would be faster, as it doesn't have to move all those elements over.

Comment: Upvote for stack analogy, but think of pipes too. As we are supposed to be programmers we should also be thinking shift is a shift-left and unshift is a shift-right on a horizontal left to right array.

Answer (score 9):

It grabs the first element, removes it from the array, and returns the removed element. It's basically a way to treat an array like a stack: `shift` is pop, `unshift` is push.

Comment: Well shift and unshift are *similar* to pop and push, except they add and remove stuff from the beginning of an array, instead from the end.

Comment: This answer is at precisely the correct level of abstraction.

Comment: @Alberto: Or, in other words, they consider the front to be the top. There's no requirement for it to be otherwise.

Comment: @Alberto: The "beginning of the array" is akin to the top of the stack.

Comment: I was just pointing out that, since `pop` and `push` are also `Array` method, confusion is not to be made. :-)

Comment: @Alberto: That's actually a good point. The shift/unshift methods use the front as top while the push/pop methods use the end as top. They both treat the array as a stack, differing only in which end they use.

Comment: Does it return the remaining array or the element that was removed?

Comment: @agentbanks217: It returns the removed element. I updated my question to remove that ambiguity.

Comment: It looks like `unshift` returns the new array while `shift` returns the removed value (or nil).

Comment: Since push and pop already provide the stack like history/depth/lift level functions, it seems to me that shift and unshift support a queue model, where we can maintain the size of an array (for instance) by pushing and shifting or popping and unshifting in combination. Emulating destructive shift left and shift right also becomes obvious. A circular shift for "round robin" purposes also springs to mind. I cannot help but associate shift with register and accumulator operations.

Comment: Alberto Santini's answer is the the easiest to read and quickly understand. imo

Answer (score 2):

If you can think of the array as being like a queue of values to be processed, then you can take the next (front) value and "shift" the other valuess over to occupy the space made available.  unshift puts values back in - maybe you're not ready to process some of them, or will let some later code handle them.

Answer (score 1):

It returns the first element of the array, and removes it from the array, *shifting* the elements back one place.

So shifting `[1,2,3,4,5]`

returns `1`, and sets the array to be `[2,3,4,5]`.

More [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002170).